# VBScript if typed response = Minute(now) Invalid procedure error

Tags: vbscript

When you type the minute to be the same as the current minute (Ex. you type in 20 and its currently 1:**20**) I want it to end the script. Instead it gives me

> Invalid procedure call or argument error.

```
Dim Ho, Mi, Se, RH, RM, RS
bOuterLoop = True
Do While bOuterLoop
reminder = InputBox(vbNewLine & "Enter a reminder for today," & " " & 
WeekdayName(Weekday(Now())) & " " & MonthName (Month(Now)) & " " & (Day(Now)) & ", " & (Year(Now)) & "!", "Set a Reminder") 
If IsEmpty(reminder) Then
  WScript.Quit
    End If
If reminder="" then
  reminder="REMINDER FOR YOU"
    end if
Ho = InputBox(vbNewLine & "At what hour would you like to be reminded?(24H)", "Time")
If IsEmpty(Ho) Then
  WScript.Quit
    End If
if Ho = "" then
  WScript.Quit
    End If
Mi = InputBox(vbNewLine & "At what minute in the hour do you want to be 
reminded?", "Time")
If IsEmpty(Mi) Then
  WScript.Quit
    End If
if Mi = "" then
  WScript.Quit
    End If
RH = Hour(Now)
RM = Minute(Now)
RS = Second(Now)
if Mi = RM then
a=msgbox(reminder, 0, "")
  wscript.quit
    end if 
Ho = Ho - RH
Se = RS
if RM > Mi then
  Mi = Mi + 60
    end if
Mi = Mi - RM
    Do
        WScript.Sleep (3600000 * Ho) + ((60000 * Mi) - (1000 * Se))
        answer = MsgBox(reminder & "   " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Would you like to snooze the reminder?     ", 4+64, "Reminder")
        If answer = vbNo Then
            WScript.Quit
            bOuterLoop = False
            Exit Do
        End If

    Loop
Loop
```

Please explain what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the logic which you are using here but I think the 'If' condition comparing the values of variables 'Mi' and 'RM' is returning False.

Suppose the current time is 1:20.

In your code, the variable Mi stores the input taken from the user which is of type **vbString**. Suppose the user enters 20. So, your variable looks something like this:

```
Mi="20"
```

The variable RM stores Minute(now) which is of type **vbInteger**. So, it would look something like this:

```
RM=20
```

Now when you compare these two variables, they are not equal. Hence, the If condition returns False and your script does not end.

You can make the following change in your code:

```
If Cint(Mi) = RM then
    a=msgbox(reminder, 0, "")
    wscript.quit
End If
```

Comment: What does Cint() do?

Comment: Cint() will convert the value contained in variable 'Mi' to Integer.

Comment: Also why does subtracting the RM from Mi work as opposed to comparing them?